# Adding response header in JAX-RS request filter

Tags: java, filter, jax-rs

I'm implementing rate limit filter in JAX-RS application (Websphere Liberty).

Main functionality will be in request filter (implementing ContainerRequestFilter interface), so I can deny request before it reaches endpoint.

However, I would also like to add response headers at the same time (e.g. X-RateLimit-Limit) in any case.

I would like to avoid writing separate ContainerResponseFilter for this purpose because performance reasons. I have all counters loaded already in Request filter.

Is there a clean way to include response headers in request filter for inclusion down the chain?

Comment: In all cases, are you trying to abort the request? Or is it just in some cases?

Comment: Just in some cases (when number of requests are exceeded).

Comment: I would just implement a response filter also. If you want _clean_, this is the cleanest way. For requests that you want to abort, just use requestContext.abortWith(Response). Set the limit header in the response filter. If you don't want to have two classes, just make the one filter class implement both interfaces. You can also set a property in the request filter if you want to forward any information from the request filter to the response filter.

Comment: Have you actually done any benchmarks? What makes you think that just adding a response filter will be a significant hit to performance?

Comment: I'm doing relatively significant processing in order to load/link rate limit rules in the filter. Those rules need to be further linked to user issuing incoming request. If I have to use two separate filters, I need to do all this linking twice.

Comment: " You can also set a property in the request filter if you want to forward any information from the request filter to the response filter." < thank you, this will do! I will set the property in requestContent, which I can access in response filter.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by passing data in requestContext from request to response filter.